# RouteProvider uses resolve property from another route definition

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I've got stuck with the following route configuration:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/common/query/:query', {
            templateUrl: 'common.html',
            controller: 'UsualResultsController',
            resolve: {
                UsualResults: usualCntrl.performSearch
            }
        })
        .when('/people/query/:query', {
            template: 'people.html',
            controller: 'PeopleResultsController',
            resolve: {
                PeopleResults: peopleCntrl.performSearch
            }
        })
        .when('/people/query/:query/department/:department', {
            template: people.html',
            controller: 'PeopleResultsController',
            resolve: {
                PeopleResults: peopleCntrl.performSearch
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

and it appears that every route switching is resolved with the 'resolve' object from the last definition.
Here is a simplified [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0YcngEmpcFIbfdfVR7Mr?p=preview).

Actually, I understand that that in routing order matters and all regex paths should be defined after static paths, but couldn't apply it to my situation.

Moreover, I suppose that the last two route definitions could be combined into one, but again I couldn't grasp, how to achieve it.

I'll be grateful for your help, guys!

Comment: try declaring a factory like that http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.controller` does not return the controller, but the module (same as `angular.module`).

In your example the following:

```
peopleCntrl.performSearch = function($timeout, $q) { ... };
```

Will replace the the function defined by:

```
usualCntrl.performSearch = function($timeout, $q) { ... };
```

Since both `peopleCntrl` and `usualCntrl` refer to the same module object.

While probably not the cleanest solution, it will work if you don't use the same name for the functions.

Another solution would be the following:

```
var usualCntrl = function UsualResultsController($scope) { ... };

app.controller('UsualResultsController', ['$scope', usualCntrl]);

usualCntrl.performSearch = function($timeout, $q) { ... };
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jx6HYDXggsaq3qMOdF8c?p=preview

Comment: thank you! That's work fine. I missed the fact that 'controller' function actually returns module instance. So, I simply altered function names.